# Perforce Commandline Get Contents of Deleted File

Tags: command-line, perforce

I've done this several times in `git`, but not sure how to do it in `p4 commandline`.  Google is not helping me - or maybe I'm not searching correctly.

I have a file that was deleted: `/path/to/file/index.html`  Now, I need to get the contents of that file as it was before being deleted.  I do not want to bring it back to life, I just need the contents.

The changelist for the `delete` is `125325`.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sync it to your workspace (this is kind of similar to the `git checkout` method that you're probably familiar with):

```
p4 sync /path/to/file/index.html@125324
```

If you just want to see the content (e.g. dump it to stdout), you can use `p4 print` (if you were to use the depot path of the file rather than a local path, `p4 print` doesn't require that the file is mapped to your workspace):

```
p4 print /path/to/file/index.html@125324
```

Note that the rev specifier I'm using is the changelist *before* the file was deleted.  You can also use the prior revision number, or an earlier rev/changelist, a particular date, etc.  See `p4 help revisions` for all the ways you can reference older versions of files.